# Bootstrap Modal Carousel not showing previous slide on previous slide link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 and trying to display a gallery of images using Bootstrap Modal carousel. I found the below mentioned code from github. Everything works fine except the previous slide link. Its not making the slider moves backward to previus slide/image. Can anybody please help me with the issue.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row thumb-gallery">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Deer Yard 1" href="#">
                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="images/Deer-Yards-1.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Deer Yard 2" href="#">
                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="images/Deer-Yards-2.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Deer Yard 3" href="#">
                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="images/Deer-Yards-3.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





 <div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!--modal content-->
    </div> <!--modal dialog-->
</div>
```

I am using the jquery code:

```
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.row .thumbnail').on('load', function() {

}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
    var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');

    var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

    item.attr("title",title);
    $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
    item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
    if (i==0){ // set first item active
     item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very small typo in your code.

This `a` tag in your HTML (omitting the icon inside):

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
```

... should be:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XaF94/) to prove it works.

When debugging, be sure to start at the source (in this case, the button itself) and work backwards to make sure every line of code is both written as expected and functioning as expected.

Comment: i really appreciate you give some time to my question. i did spent whole day messing with the code. now its working exactly i want it to be :)

Answer (score -3):

In the above code href should be href="#modalCarousel" instead of href="#modaCarousel"

Comment: This is a bad copy of an answer that was accepted 8 months ago.